# Как вынести метод dispatch() в миксин если у меня две разных модели используются?

Tags: python, django

у меня две модели Post и Comment. Ревьюер просит избавиться от дублирования кода и объединить из функций методы dispatch() чтобы код не повторялся. Вот сточки кода которые надо соединить

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    publication = get_object_or_404(**Post**, pk=kwargs['pk'])
    if publication.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', id=kwargs['pk'])
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    comment = get_object_or_404(**Comment**, pk=kwargs['pk'])
    if comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', comment.post_id)
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```